# How to use the XML Response from Server?

Tags: objective-c, xml, uitableview

I am programming an app which makes an online search on a private server and shows the results to the users. I want to use a table view to show the results.

What I can is: send data, receive a response and parse the XML and save the results in an array.

The problem is : I can not access the array, which stores the response Data, out of the method : `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`.

But I am able to access the same array, within this method. I am a beginner and I got confused. I created an instance variable and initialised with the searchResults array in the method `connectionDidFinishLoading`, but when I try to access this array out of the Method:connectionDidFinishLoading, I am always getting the error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array`

I just cannot understand why this instance variable is only local initialised.

So the question is: how can I access the data which I get from the server out of the Method: `connectionDidFinishLoading`?

Here is my code:

```
-  (void)transmitXMLRequest:(NSData *)data{
    NSURL *webServiceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some_url"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:webServiceURL];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:data];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [connection start];


    if (!connection) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to submit request");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Request submitted");
    }    
}
```

And the delegate methods:

```
-     (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{    
    // responseData is an instance variable.
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // responseData is an instance variable.   
    [responseData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    connection = nil;
    responseData = nil;

    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}
```

I can access the data only within this method:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[responseData length]);

    responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Received file: \n%@", responseString);


    NSData *_data= [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc]loadXML:_data];    // _data is the response from server

    controller.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    controller.searchResults = [xmlParser jobs];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use SOAP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP

> SOAP, originally defined as Simple Object Access Protocol, is a protocol specification for exchanging structured information in the
>   implementation of Web Services in computer networks.    It relies on Extensible Markup Language (XML) for its message format, and usually relies on other Application Layer protocols, most
>   notably Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) and Simple Mail Transfer
>   Protocol (SMTP), for message negotiation and transmission.